# Yii2: using find() to filter with attributes and one() performs a select all instead of filtering

Tags: yii2

I've this line of code

```
Product::find(['internal_code' => $code])->one();
```

I was expecting a SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product 
WHERE internal_code = '<code_var_value>'
```

Instead, debug toolbar show me a flat

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product
```

So, even if `internal_code` is not found, the result of a select all piped with `one()` is that the first record of the tabòe (even if not matching) is retrieved.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I misunderstood the documentation.

This is the solution

```
Product::find()->where(['internal_code' => $code])->one();
```